# Sense of $d(adz_i\otimes dz_j)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

Is $d(adz_i\otimes dz_j)$ having any sense ? Maybe you can see the tensor as a form valued as a form, but how do you know where you differentiate $a$ ? As $da\wedge dz_i\otimes dz_j$ or $dz_i\otimes da\wedge dz_j$ ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Maybe this could be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_covariant_derivative

Comment: What makes you think this should make any sense? If you change coordinates, can you make something well-defined?

Comment: What space are you working on?  A manifold? $\mathbb{C}^n$?  Is $a$ a function on your space?  Are the $z_i$ real coordinates or complex coordinates or something else?  You should clearly define all the objects in your question.  Otherwise, it will be difficult for people to help you.